# How to correct css for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Now I m working on [this site](http://www.filmulmeu.ucoz.com)

So far it is looking OK on all the browsers except `IE`. I don't know why in `IE` he is aligned to the left. How can I detect what causes this? Is there a way to detect what are the problems with CSS in IE ?!

CSS:

```
  html,body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
text-align:left;
border:0px;
background:#000000 url(/design/wrap_t_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:11px;
color:#434343;}
```

Comment: Please post some examples of what is going wrong in IE and which version your talking about.

Comment: Because IE is not that "good" with web standards. Did you google something about browsers compatibility? On the web there are a lot of tables that show the cross-browser compatibility. EG [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/2mi2lo4.png this is how it looks in ie :( maybe on a smaller resolution it looks ok but on a higher one nor

Comment: @user2026426 Use imgur.com

Comment: Just use `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this part:**

```
html,body{
margin:0px;
```

To:

```
html,body{
margin:0px auto;
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Quirks Mode Issue**

By default, the site goes in quirks mode. So, can you please add this to the first line?

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: @user2026426 Make sure that the document mode is not quirks mode.

Comment: Indeed, my IE9 defaults to quirks mode for this website. If I force it to render in standards mode, it looks better but not the same as in FF. IF you hit F12 to launch the developer tool, you are likely to see "Document mode: quirks mode" or similar to the right of the menu bar.

Comment: @user2026426 Add the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Did you also add the `margin: 0 auto;`? If you have uploaded, can I check it live?

Comment: No can't find the doctype. Have you really added?

Comment: yes i added it it really works thx the problem is that my free host ads his ads content before my code .. when i will get a premium account it will look ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change text-align in body to 'center' and overwrite it in the div's.

Please use a html validator. There are some horrible errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods to write css for IE .. 
first is like this ..on html pages
Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
```

other is using fallback methods on css pages
example.. .

```
html > body #div {
  height: 300px;
```

}

best you read this article. .
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/